# Return list from JSON call in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

EDIT:

ENTIRE DART FILE  -- Here is the entire dart file. Im not seeing how to call the method in the ARR declaration and return the correct mapping. Just need to generate the array from the http call and we are good. This is our first run at returning multiple records from JSON and iterating thru it.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:lightbridge_mobile/screens/forum/assets/colors.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:lightbridge_mobile/screens/forum/assets/app_bar_forum.dart';
import 'package:lightbridge_mobile/models/forum_answers.dart';
 import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 class ForumDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _ForumDetailPageState createState() => new _ForumDetailPageState();
}

 class _ForumDetailPageState extends State<ForumDetailPage> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var questionSection = new Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Text(
        // Post Title
        "How do I become a expert in programming as well as design ??",
        textScaleFactor: 1.5,
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0 ),
      ),
      new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            new IconWithText(Icons.laptop_windows, "Technology", iconColor: Colors.grey),
            new IconWithText(
              Icons.question_answer,
              "Answered",
              iconColor: Colors.grey,
            ),
            new IconWithText(Icons.remove_red_eye, "54", iconColor: Colors.grey)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      new Divider( height: 1.0)
    ],
  ),
);

var responses = new Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

  child: new ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new ForumPost(ForumPostArr[index]),
    itemCount: ForumPostArr.length,
  )
);

return new Scaffold(
   appBar : LBForumAppBar().getAppBar(),
  body: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      questionSection,
      new Expanded(
          child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
        child: responses,
      ))
    ],
  ),
);
 }
}

var ForumPostArr =  [
 new ForumPostEntry("User1", "2 Days ago", 0 , 0 , "Hello,\n\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."),
 new ForumPostEntry("User2", "23 Hours ago", 1 , 0 , "Pellentesque justo metus, finibus porttitor consequat vitae, tincidunt vitae quam. Vestibulum molestie sem diam. Nullam pretium semper tempus. Maecenas lobortis lacus nunc, id lacinia nunc imperdiet tempor. Mauris mi ipsum, finibus consectetur eleifend a, maximus eget lorem. Praesent a magna nibh. In congue sapien sed velit mattis sodales. Nam tempus pulvinar metus, in gravida elit tincidunt in. Curabitur sed sapien commodo, fringilla tortor eu, accumsan est. Proin tincidunt convallis dolor, a faucibus sapien auctor sodales. Duis vitae dapibus metus. Nulla sit amet porta ipsum, posuere tempor tortor.\n\nCurabitur mauris dolor, cursus et mi id, mattis sagittis velit. Duis eleifend mi et ante aliquam elementum. Ut feugiat diam enim, at placerat elit semper vitae. Phasellus vulputate quis ex eu dictum. Cras sapien magna, faucibus at lacus vel, faucibus viverra lorem. Phasellus quis dui tristique, ultricies velit non, cursus lectus. Suspendisse neque nisl, vestibulum non dui in, vulputate placerat elit. Sed at convallis mauris, eu blandit dolor. Vivamus suscipit iaculis erat eu condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur posuere commodo arcu vel consectetur."),
  new ForumPostEntry("User3", "2 Days ago", 5 , 0 , "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."),
   new ForumPostEntry("User4", "2 Days ago", 0 , 0 , "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."),

  ];




  Future<List<ForumAnswers>> getForumAnswers(String postID) async {

  final response =
     await http.post('http://api/ForumAnswers',
     headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
     body: json.encode({'PostID' : postID }));  

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON

 List l = json.decode(response.body);
   List<ForumAnswers> posts = l.map((m) => ForumAnswers.fromJson(m)).toList(); 


  return posts;

} else {
// If that call was not successful, throw an error.
throw Exception('Failed to load user');
 }

  }


class ForumPostEntry{
  final String username;
  final String hours;
  final int likes;
  final int dislikes;
  final String text;

     ForumPostEntry(this.username, this.hours, this.likes, this.dislikes, this.text);
}

class ForumPost extends StatelessWidget {
  final ForumPostEntry entry;

  ForumPost(this.entry);

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(20.0)),
     ),
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: 50.0,
              color: Colors.white
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(
                    entry.username
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    entry.hours
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: new Text(entry.likes.toString()),
                ),
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_down, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, left: 2.0),
                  child: new Text(entry.dislikes.toString()),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0,right: 2.0,bottom: 2.0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft :const Radius.circular(20.0),bottomRight :const Radius.circular(20.0))
        ),
        child: new Text(entry.text),
      ),
    ],
    ),
   );
}
 }

  class IconWithText extends StatelessWidget {
 final IconData iconData;
 final String text;
 final Color iconColor;

  IconWithText(this.iconData, this.text, {this.iconColor});
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Container(
    child: new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Icon(
        this.iconData,
        color: this.iconColor,
      ),
      new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
        child: new Text(this.text),
      ),
       ],
  ),
    );
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your json consists of an array at the outer most level; it's enclosed in `[..]`.

`l`, the result of `json.decode` will be a `List<dynamic>`, though the list will happen to contain `Map`s.

You should find that this works better:

```
 List l = json.decode(response.body);
 List<ForumAnswers> posts = l.map((m) => ForumAnswers.fromJson(m)).toList();
```

Note that if you want to return `posts` you should change the signature to returning `Future<List<ForumAnswers>>`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. How would I loop thru the results and create this string? "new ForumPostEntry("User1", "2 Days ago", 0 , 0 , "Post content here"),"

Comment: `posts.map((p)=>ForumPostEntry(p.username, daysAgo(p.createDate), 0, 0, p.content)).toList();`

Comment: awesome thank u. I have one more question for you. Is it possible to call a method and generate that array? I'll add the array definition and the method call. When the screen loads I want to make the http call and generate the array to fill the forum answers.

Comment: yes, just return the `posts.map(...).toList()` list. That *is* a `List<ForumPostEntry>`.

Comment: Can I call it in the array? I added the code to EDIT 2

Comment: var ForumPostArr = [

  new ForumPostEntry("User1", "2 Days ago", 0 , 0 , "Answer 1"),
   new ForumPostEntry("User1", "2 Days ago", 0 , 0 , "Answer 2"),
    new ForumPostEntry("User1", "2 Days ago", 0 , 0 , "Answer 3"),
];

Comment: ForumPostArr fills the forum answers so we want to generate the array from the http call Future<List<ForumAnswers>> getForumAnswers(String postID) async {

Comment: That's exactly what `posts.map(...).toList()` is! A `List<ForumPostEntry>`. Just assign it to `ForumPostArr` (which I'd rename to `forumPosts` to be more darty). `List<ForumPostEntry> forumPosts = posts.map((p)=>ForumPostEntry(p.username, daysAgo(p.createDate), 0, 0, p.content)).toList();`

Comment: thank u very much for all the help. Where would I call the method?  var forumPosts = getForumAnswers(postID);

Comment: sorry Im not seeing how to do this yet, I can post the entire dart file if that would help

Comment: I added the entire file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191034/discussion-between-richard-heap-and-sam-cromer).

Answer (score 0):

use these

factory ForumAnswers.fromJson(Map parsedjson) {
    return ForumAnswers(

```
  content: parsedjson['content'],
  username: parsedjson['username'],
  createDate : parsedjson['createDate'],
  upvote : parsedjson['upvote'],

);
```

if not follow these link   https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Comment: what is parsedjson? its not defined